# Can I still be a true Muslim if I am rich or trying to be rich?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, money

Many of my Muslim friends say they are not interested to acquire rich but their actions do or show the exact opposite of their words.

My question is can I become a millionaire plus being in a pure soul, heart, mind and or aligning with the Prophet Muhammad PBUH principles, & still be a true Muslim.

Comment: Thanks for your response brother.I meant whole true, as much as principles I follows & applies (Depends on my capability & consciousness).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having a desire of being rich. What is wrong in Islam is trying to acquire wealth through the wrong means. Being true to yourself and Allah Tala is the most important thing to do here. If you are truly working hard to earn money then there is nothing wrong with it. But you need to remember that what you earn should also be shared with the people who need it. Allah has taught us to donate a share of what we earn. This is what makes us true Muslims.

Answer (score 2):

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*Verily, Allah does not look to your faces and your wealth but He looks to your heart and to your deeds.*" Muslim ([2564c](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2564c))

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “*O Abu Dharr, do you say an abundance of possessions is wealth?*” I said yes. The Prophet said: “*Do you say a lack of possessions is poverty*” I said yes. The Prophet repeated this three times, then he said: “*Wealth is in the heart and poverty is in the heart. Whoever is wealthy in his heart will not be harmed no matter what happens in the world. Whoever is impoverished in his heart will not be satisfied no matter how much he has in the world. Verily, he will only be harmed by the greed of his own soul.*” Al-Mu’jam al-Kabir ([1643](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/1977#p1)) graded Sahih by Sheikh Albani in Sahih al-Jam‘i ([7816](https://al-maktaba.org/book/10757/1223#p1))

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*Whoever absorbs his heart in love of the world will be entangled by three things: misery that will not cease to discomfort him, greed that will not achieve his independence, and vain hopes that will never reach their end. For the world is seeking and is sought. Whoever seeks the world, the Hereafter will pursue him until death comes to him and it seizes him. Whoever seeks the Hereafter, the world will pursue him until he exhausts his provision from it.*" Al-Mu’jam al-Kabir ([10328](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/12328#p1)) graded Hasan by Al-I'raqi in Al-Ihya (p. [578](https://shamela.ws/book/21550/4128))

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*Whoever is focused only on this world, Allah will confound his affairs and make him constantly fear poverty, and he will not get anything of this world except that which has been decreed for him. Whoever is focused on the Hereafter, Allah will settle his affairs for him and make him feel content with his lot, and his provision and worldly gains will undoubtedly come to him.*" Ibn Majah ([4105](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4105)) graded Sahih by Sheikh Albani in As-Sahihah ([950](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/1576))

And that is why Ibn al-Qayyim said in Madarij As-Salikin (1/463):

> "*When there is money in your hand and not in your heart, it will not harm you, even if it is a lot; and when it is in your heart, it will harm you, even if there is none in your hands*."

What all of this should tell you is that you can have aspirations for a lot of wealth, but it has to go along with the attitude that you should only seek the Akhira, know and contemplate about what wealth can do to you. But of course, there is nothing wrong with enjoying and appreciating what Allah gives you, and that you show gratitude towards Allah. Yet, wealth is a great test and most people fail to handle it, and what harm it can inflict in your heart/onto you or around you.

---

<sup>[Here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/73765/what-is-islam-saying-about-the-dunyah-and-what-should-be-the-intention-as-well/73768#73768) is a detailed answer to this topic.</sup>

Comment: Thank you brother for your response.

Answer (score 0):

One condition: If your intention is to make yourself happy, your family happy and every Muslim happy.

Do you know Abd al-Rahman's Ibn Auf?

He was one of the companions of the Islamic prophet Muhammad. One of the wealthiest sahabas, he is known for being one of the Ten Promised Paradise. Can you imagine?

Many stories are told of 'Abd al-Rahman's personal generosity. He once furnished Muhammad's army with 1,500 camels. He bequeathed 400 dinars to the survivors of Badr and a large legacy to the widows of Muhammad. One day he brought a caravan of 700 merchant-camels into Medina. Aisha remarked, "I have heard Allah's Messenger say: 'I have seen 'Abd al-Rahman ibn Awf entering Paradise crawling.'" This was repeated to 'Abd al-Rahman, who replied: "If I could, I would certainly like to enter Paradise standing. I swear to you, yaa Ammah, that this entire caravan with all its merchandise, I will give in charity." And so he did.

So if you want to be rich, be please and have fun and help people to be happy as well. And Allah will give you more and more.