# What is Islam saying about the Dunya, and what should be the intention as well as goal of a worshipper of Allah?

Tags: quran, hadith

I would like to ask about all the authentic ahadith and verses from the Qu'ran (if possible) regarding the Dunya/Akhira (this world/hereafter), about wealth and its values/benefits in Islam. **[1]—** Can someone share the collection of the knowledge (ahadith/ayat) in this regard?

And, imagine someone worships Allah with the intention to achieve success in this world with a little consciousness of the hereafter, meaning that since the materialistic world is now the utmost reality (*family issues, financial issues, marriage life, calamities*) to him rather than the promise of Allah (*because he may be overwhelmed by the hardships that he has gone through or perhaps he wants now to become successful in this life also*), so he prioritises this world over the hereafter. **[2]—** So what has Islam taught us to do concerning this whole matter? Or can you elaborate this issue with authentic evidence?

I ask Allah to guide me and everybody around me, and to grant us the level of the righteous slaves of Him.

Comment: You should split the question as alone the qur'an verses request regarding this topic could blow up the borders of the answer field. And I wonder why you've accepted an answer which even didn't quote any qur'an quote while you want "all verses and ahadith" according your question text! Further I'm not clear whether a list question especially a full-list request would fit our site policy, because it is hardly achievable especially because the interpretation of the relevance of verses and ahadith is subjective and because you can hardly post all ahadith on this topic.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, my answer has been revised to include Quraanic ayats. Furthermore, an the ahadith are not separate from the Quraan. If there is either or it does not matter as long as it answers the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are following Ahadith concerning this topic to better understand how to deal with worldly matters, how they can impact you during the Dunya as well as influence your Akhira:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*Verily, Allah does not look to your faces and your wealth, but He looks to your heart and to your deeds.*"
>
> <sup>Muslim ([2564c](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2564c)), and in ([2564b](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2564b)):</sup>
>
> "*Verily, Allah does not look to your bodies nor to your faces, but He looks to your hearts*" - 'and he pointed towards the heart with his fingers.'
>
> ---
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*O Abu Dharr, do you say an abundance of possessions is wealth?*" 'I said: Yes.' The Prophet said: "*Do you say a lack of possessions is poverty?*" 'I said: Yes. The Prophet repeated this three times, then he said': "*Wealth is in the heart and poverty is in the heart. Whoever is wealthy in his heart will not be harmed no matter what happens in the world. Whoever is impoverished in his heart will not be satisfied, no matter how much he has in the world. Verily, he will only be harmed by the greed of his own soul.*"
>
> <sup>Mu'jam al-Kabir ([1643](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/1977#p1)) graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani in Sahih al-Jam'i ([7816](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/1223#p1))</sup>
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*Whoever absorbs his heart in love of the world will be entangled by three things: misery that will not cease to discomfort him, greed that will not achieve his independence, and vain hopes that will never reach their end. For the world is seeking and is sought. Whoever seeks the world, the Hereafter will pursue him until death comes to him and it seizes him. Whoever seeks the Hereafter, the world will pursue him until he exhausts his provision from it.*"
>
> <sup>Mu'jam al-Kabir ([10328](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/12328#p1)) graded Hasan Isnad by Al-I'raqi in Al-Ihya (p. [578](https://shamela.ws/book/21550/4128)), but Shaykh Albani objected in Ad-Da'ifah ([6650](https://shamela.ws/book/12762/10319#p1)) and classed it Da'if</sup>

But, we have further Ahadith which refer similarly for the above mentioned, objected narration:

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*Whoever is focused only on this world, Allah will confound his affairs and make him constantly fear poverty, and he will not get anything of this world except that which has been decreed for him. Whoever is focused on the Hereafter, Allah will settle his affairs for him and make him feel content with his lot, and his provision and worldly gains will undoubtedly come to him.*"
>
> <sup>Ibn Majah ([4105](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4105)) graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani in As-Sahihah (2/534 - #[950](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/1576))</sup>
>
> "*Allah says*": "***O son of Adam, devote yourself to My worship, and I will fill your heart with contentment and take care of your poverty, but if you do not do that, then I will fill your heart with worldly concerns and will not take care of your poverty.***"
>
> <sup>Ibn Majah ([4107](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4107)) classed Sahih in Sahihut-Targhib ([3166](https://shamela.ws/book/179/1570))</sup>
>
> <sup>In At-Tirmidhi ([2465](https://al-maktaba.org/book/782/2465)), which Shaykh Albani declared weak in As-Sahihah (2/533-4 - #[949](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/1575)), yet it has Sahih follow-ups with other narrations, therefore graded those Sahih li Ghayrihi in Sahih at-Targhib ([3169](https://shamela.ws/book/171/1570)), that it is narrated (with different variations):</sup>
>
> "*Whoever makes the Hereafter his goal, Allah makes his heart rich, and organizes his affairs, and the world comes to him whether it wants to or not. And whoever makes the world his goal, Allah puts his poverty right before his eyes, and disorganizes his affairs, and the world does not come to him, except what has been decreed for him.*"
>
> <sup>In Ibn Majah ([4106](https://shamela.ws/book/1198/5639)), classed Hasan li Ghayrihi in Sahih at-Targhib ([3171](https://shamela.ws/book/171/1571#p7)), it is narrated:</sup>
>
> "*Whoever focuses on only one concern, the afterlife, Allah will be enough for his concerns in the world. Whoever scatters his concerns among the matters of the world, it does not matter to Allah in which valley he meets his demise.*"
>
> <sup>And in Az-Zuhd li-Ibn Abi Asim ([161](https://shamela.ws/book/13026/171)), graded Hasan in As-Sahihah (7/349-50 - #[3287](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/5658)), it is narrated:</sup>
>
> "*Whoever seeks the world will be harmed in the Hereafter, and whoever seeks the Hereafter will be harmed in the world. Thus, be harmed by the ephemeral for the sake of the everlasting.*"

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*When Allah loves a servant, he protects them from the world, just as one of you keeps the sick from drinking too much water.*"
>
> <sup>At-Tirmidhi ([2036](https://al-maktaba.org/book/782/2036)) noted as Sahih by Shaykh Albani</sup>
>
> "*Allah says*": "***We have sent down the money to establish prayer and to pay zakat*** [...]
>
> <sup>Mu'jam al-Kabir ([3301](https://shamela.ws/book/1733/3941#p1)-3) and classed Sahih in Sahih al-Jam'i ([1781](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/304))</sup>

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*Indeed, there is a fitnah for every Ummah, and the Fitnah for my Ummah is wealth.*" At-Tirmidhi ([2336](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2336)) and Abu I'sa classed it Sahih Gharib, in ([2337](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2337)), classed Hasan Sahih Gharib, it is narrated: "*If the Son of Adam had a valley of gold, then he would still like to have a second (one).* [Additionally, from Mu'jam al-Kabir (3301): ***and if he had two valleys, he would love to have a third***], *and nothing fills his mouth but dust, and Allah forgives those who repent*", and in ([2339](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2339)), classed Sahih, it is narrated: "*The Son of Adam grows old, but two things keep him young: Desire for life and desire for wealth.*"

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*Let the slave of Dinar and Dirham, of Quantify and Khamisa perish as he is pleased if these things are given to him, and if not, he is displeased. Let such a person perish and relapse, and if he is pierced with a thorn, let him not find anyone to take it out for him. Paradise is for him who holds the reins of his horse to strive in Allah's Cause...*"
>
> <sup>Al-Bukhari ([2887](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2887))</sup>

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*Do not take to the estate, such that you become desirous of the world.*"
>
> <sup>At-Tirmidhi ([2328](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2328)) and Abu I'sa classed it Hasan</sup>

> Thereupon he (ﷺ) said: "*Be happy and be hopeful of that which gives you delight. By Allah, it is not the poverty about which I fear in regard to you, but I am afraid in your case that (the worldly) riches way be given to you as were given to those who had gone before you and you begin to vie with one another for them as they vied for them, and these may destroy you as these destroyed them.*"
>
> <sup>Muslim ([2961a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2961a))</sup>

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*My nation will be afflicted by the diseases of the former nations.*" [...] "*Excessive amusement, pride and arrogance, disunity, competition for worldly gain, hatred, and greed until there is transgression followed by war.*"
>
> <sup>Mu'jam al-Awsat ([9016](https://shamela.ws/book/28171/9405)), Al-Mustadrak ([4/185](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/8143)) graded Sahih by Al-Hakim and Imam Dhahabi agreed; Hasan in Sahih al-Jam'i ([3658](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/620))</sup>

> "*The piety is here*" - '(and while saying so) he pointed towards his chest thrice.' "*It is a serious evil for a Muslim that he should look down upon his brother Muslim. All things of a Muslim are inviolable for his brother in faith: his blood, his wealth and his honour.*"
>
> <sup>Muslim ([2564a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2564a))</sup>

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*Wealth is not in having many possessions, but rather (true) wealth is feeling sufficiency in the soul.*"
>
> <sup>Al-Bukhari ([6446](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6446))</sup>

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "[...] *Give up trying to acquire what people have and you will be wealthy.* [...]"
>
> <sup>Mu'jam al-Awsat ([4427](https://shamela.ws/book/28171/4687)) graded Sahih in Sahih al-Jam'i ([3776](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/639))</sup>

> 'Then he spoke to the people about being rich.' He said: "*There is nothing wrong with being rich for one who has piety, but good health for one who has piety is better than riches, and being of good cheer is a blessing.*"
>
> <sup>Ibn Majah ([2141](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2141)) graded Sahih</sup>

> "*O people, fear Allah and be moderate in seeking a living, for no soul will die until it has received all its provision, even if it is slow in coming. So fear Allah and be moderate in seeking provision; take that which is permissible and leave that which is forbidden*"
>
> <sup>Ibn Majah ([2144](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2144)) graded Sahih | What is meant by "be moderate in seeking a living" is: Seek provision in a gentle manner, and the Prophet (ﷺ) explained what is meant by that, which is to take that which is permissible and leave that which is forbidden. | And, we have a narration in Sunan al-Kubra lil Bayhaqi ([10501](https://shamela.ws/book/148486/5994#p1)), graded Sahih in Sahih al-Jam'i ([157](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/32)), that it is narrated:</sup>
>
> "*Be moderate in seeking from the world, for everyone will be facilitated towards what has been decreed for him in it.*"

> He (ﷺ) said: "*Amr, sound (legitimately acquired) wealth is very excellent for a righteous man!*"
>
> <sup>Adab al-Mufrad ([299](https://sunnah.com/urn/2302970)) and in Musnad Ahmad ([17763](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/14253#p1)) graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani in Sahih Mawarid ([2277](https://shamela.ws/book/14440/917))</sup>
>
> <sup>Imam Dhahabi quotes Fudyal ibn I'yad in his book Siyar a'lam al-Nubala ([8/426](https://shamela.ws/book/10906/5552#p1)), who said: 'People have not adorned themselves with anything better than honesty and seeking lawful [sustenance].'</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Not only to gain wealth, but also related to wasting it, it is narrated in Al-Bazzar ([8463](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12981/8315#p1)), which was classed Sahih in As-Sahihah (2/298 - #[685](https://shamela.ws/book/9442/1240)), that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*Allah does not like for you to waste wealth...*"

> He (ﷺ) then said: "*When Allah gives you property, let the mark of Allah's favour and honour to you be seen.*"
>
> <sup>Abu Dawud ([4063](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4063)) classed Sahih by Shaykh Albani</sup>

---

And that is why Ibn al-Qayyim wrote in Madarij As-Salikin ([1/463](https://shamela.ws/book/8370/435)):

> 'When there is money in your hand and not in your heart, it will not harm you, even if it is a lot; and when it is in your heart, it will harm you, even if there is none in your hands.'

And he wrote in his Zad al-Ma'ad (3/235):

> 'Most people – in fact, all of them except those protected by Allah – assume other than the truth, and assume the worst. Most people believe that they are deprived of their rights, have bad luck, deserve more than what Allah gave them, and it is as if they are saying: 'My Lord has wronged me and deprived me of what I deserve', and his soul bears witness to this while his tongue denies it and refuses to openly state this. And whoever digs into his soul and comes to know its ins and outs will see this in it [is] like fire in a triggered explosion… and if you dig into anyone's soul, you will see that he blames fate and would rather have something else happen to him than what actually did, and that things should be this way or that… So, dig into your own self: Are you protected from this? If you are safe from this, you have been protected from something great. Otherwise, I do not see that you have been saved.'

For this quote, it is befitting to cite the narration which is mentioned in Al-Bukhari ([7405](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7405)) that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:

> "*Allah says*": "***I am just as My slave thinks I am (i.e. I am able to do for him what he thinks I can do for him) and I am with him if He remembers Me. If he remembers Me in himself, I too, remember him in Myself; and if he remembers Me in a group of people, I remember him in a group that is better than they; and if he comes one span nearer to Me, I go one cubit nearer to him; and if he comes one cubit nearer to Me, I go a distance of two outstretched arms nearer to him; and if he comes to Me walking, I go to him running***";  and in Ibn Hibban ([639](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31691/1297#p1)): "*Allah says*": "***I am as My servants expects of Me. If he thinks good of Me, he will have it. If he thinks evil of Me, he will have it.***"

That is why the Prophet (ﷺ) taught us how to deal with fate when it goes contrary to our notion (for example related to business, wealth, and so on):

> "*A strong believer is better and is more lovable to Allah than a weak believer, and there is good in everyone, (but) cherish that which gives you benefit (in the Hereafter) and seek help from Allah and do not lose heart, and if anything (in the form of trouble) comes to you, don't say: "If I had not done that, it would not have happened so and so", but say: "Allah did what He had ordained to do"* (Qadarul-lah wa ma sha'a fa'al) *and your "if" opens the (gate) for Shaytan.*" Muslim ([2664](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2664)); and in Musnad Ahmad ([12160](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/9428)), classed Sahih in Sahih al-Jam'i ([3985](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/672)), the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*I am amazed by the believer. Verily, Allah does not decree anything for the believer except what is good for him.*" | "***Indeed, [Allah] extends provision for whom He wills of His servants and restricts [it] for him. But whatever thing you spend [in His cause] - He will compensate it; and He is the best of providers.***" [Sab'a 34:39] | The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*Anyone who wants to have his provision expanded and his term of life prolonged should maintain ties of kinship.*" Al-Bukhari ([5986](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5986)) - For further information about fate or al-Qadr, read these: [1](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/49004/belief-of-ahl-al-sunnah-concerning-al-qada-wal-qadar-divine-will-and-decree), [2](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/34732/meaning-of-belief-in-al-qadar-the-divine-will-and-decree), [3](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/20806/is-mans-fate-pre-destined-or-does-he-have-freedom-of-will), [4](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/112107/are-rizq-provision-and-marriage-written-in-al-lawh-al-mahfooz), [5](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/43021/nothing-exists-except-by-the-will-and-decree-of-allaah)

- Some general narrations:

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*Three people have a guarantee from Allah. If he lives he will have provision to suffice him, and if he dies he will enter Paradise: One who enters* [house] *and greets with peace* [As-Salamu A'laykum] *has a guarantee from Allah, one who goes out to the mosque has a guarantee from Allah, and one who goes out in the way of Allah has a guarantee from Allah.*" Ibn Hibban ([499](https://shamela.ws/book/1729/874#p1)) and Abu Dawud ([2494](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2494)) which Shaykh Albani classed Sahih in Sahih Abu Dawud ([2253](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25881/2884#p1))

> From Sakhr Al-Ghamidi that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*O Allah, bless my Ummah in what they do early (in the day).*" [...] And Sakhr, a man who was a merchant, used to send his goods for trade during the beginning of the day, so he became rich, and his wealth increased. [Abu I'sa said:] 'The Hadith from Sakhr Al-Ghamidi is a Hasan Hadith. We do not know of a narration that Sakhr Al-Ghamidi reported from the Prophet (ﷺ) other than this Hadith. Sufyan Ath-Thawri reported this Hadith from Shu'bah, from Ya'la bin 'Ata.' Narrated in At-Tirmidhi ([1212](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1212)); Ibn Majah ([2236](https://shamela.ws/book/1198/3003#p1)), in Musnad Ahmad ([15443](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/11722#p1), [19479](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/16004)) and others; classed as Sahih by Shaykh Albani in Sahih Abu Dawud ([2345](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25881/2990)) to which he said: '...and strengthened by Ibn Abd al-Barr, al-Mundhiri, al-Hafiz Ibn Hajar, and As-Sakhawi.' And it is narrated that U'mar ibn Khattab said: 'No one should sell in our markets, except one who has understanding in the religion.' At-Tirmidhi ([487](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:487)), which Shaykh Albani graded with a Hasan Isnad in Jam'i al-Fawayid ([4606](https://shamela.ws/book/36446/4750)); Al-Bukhari ([2079](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2079)): Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "*The seller and the buyer have the right to keep or return goods as long as they have not parted or till they part; and if both the parties spoke the truth and described the defects and qualities (of the goods), then they would be blessed in their transaction, and if they told lies or hid something, then the blessings of their transaction would be lost*"; and in Ibn Kathir stated in his Tafsir (8/123): 'That is, when you are buying and selling, giving and taking, remember Allah much, and do not let this world distract you from that which will benefit you in the Hereafter.' <sup><sup>[market](https://sunnah.com/search?q=market)</sup></sup> <sup><sup>[trade](https://sunnah.com/search?q=trade)</sup></sup> <sup><sup>[charity](https://sunnah.com/search?q=charity)</sup></sup>

> Nu'aym ibn Hammar: 'I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say': "*Allah, the Exalted, says*": "***Son of Adam, do not be helpless in performing four Rak'at for Me at the beginning of the day*** (Ad-Duha prayer)***: I will supply for what you need till the end of it.***" Abu Dawud ([1289](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1289)) graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani
>
> <sup>'A'isha said: 'The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) prayed the Duha prayer and then said': "*Ya Allah, forgive me and turn to me - You are the Ever-Turning back (to his slaves), the Merciful*" (Allahum-maghfirli wa tub a'lay-ya - Innaka antat-tau-wabur-Rahim) a hundred times.' Adab al-Mufrad ([619](https://sunnah.com/adab:619)) graded Sahih | Allah says: "***Seek forgiveness of your Lord and repent to Him, [and] He will let you enjoy a good provision for a specified term and give every doer of favor his favor. But if you turn away, then indeed, I fear for you the punishment of a great Day.***" [Hud 11:3] - "***Ask forgiveness of your Lord. Indeed, He is ever a Perpetual Forgiver. He will send [rain from] the sky upon you in [continuing] showers, and give you increase in wealth and children and provide for you gardens and provide for you rivers.***" [Nuh 10-12]</sup>

> Narrated Zaid bin Aslam: 'I heard U'mar bin Al-Khattab saying': 'We were ordered by the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) to give in charity, and that coincided with a time in which I had some wealth, so I said: Today I will beat Abu Bakr, if ever I beat him.' 'So I came with half of my wealth, and the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said': "*What did you leave for your family (with)?*" 'I said: 'The like of it.' And Abu Bakr came with everything he had, so he said': "*O Abu Bakr, what did you leave for your family (with)?*" 'He said': 'I left Allah and His Messenger for them.' 'I said: [By Allah] I will never be able to beat him to something.' At-Tirmidhi ([3675](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/49/71)) and Abu I'sa classed it Hasan Sahih

> Umar bin Al-Khattab narrated that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
> "*If you were to rely upon Allah with the required reliance, then He would provide for you just as a bird is provided for, it goes out in the morning empty, and returns full.*" At-Tirmidhi ([2344](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2344)) and Abu I'sa classed it Hasan Sahih | Allah says: "***And put your trust in Allah, for Allah is sufficient as a Trustee of Affairs.***" [Al-Ahzab 33:3] - "***And in Allah let the believers put their trust.*** [Ibrahim 14:11] | Abu Hazim was asked during an economical crisis: 'O Abu Hazim, do you not see how prices have risen?' He replied: 'Why does that bother you? Verily, He [Allah] who provides for us during deflation is the one who will provide for us during inflation." Hilyat al-Awliya ([3/239](https://shamela.ws/book/10495/4317#p1))

The above Ahadith underline that you should only rely on Allah alone and only ask aid from Him (for example, if you are in financial trouble, and son on) because it is mentioned in At-Tirmidhi ([2516](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2516)), which Abu I'sa classed Hasan Sahih, that Ibn A'bbas narrated:

> "One day, I was behind the Prophet (ﷺ), when he said: "*O boy, I will teach you a statement: Be mindful of Allah and He will protect you. Be mindful of Allah and you will find Him before you. When you ask, ask Allah, and when you seek aid, seek Allah's aid. Know that if the entire creation were to gather together to do something to benefit you, you would never get any benefit except that Allah had written for you. And if they were to gather to do something to harm you, you would never be harmed except that Allah had written for you. The pens are lifted and the pages are dried!*" Moreover, since in the latter Hadith it is mentioned that everything has been already "written", it is narrated in Muslim ([2644](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2644)) that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*When the drop of (semen) remains in the womb for forty or forty five nights, the angel comes and says: My Lord, will he be good or evil? And both these things would be written. Then the angel says: My Lord, would he be male or female? And both these things are written. And his deeds and actions, his death, his Rizq (provision, sustenance); these are also recorded. Then his document of destiny is rolled and there is no addition to nor subtraction from it*"; (Seeking Assistance From Allah) The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*You gain no victory or livelihood except through* (the blessings and invocations of) *the poor amongst you.*" Al-Bukhari ([2896](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2896)); and: "*Seek for Me, weak people, for you are provided means of subsistence and helped through your weakness.*" At-Tirmidhi ([1702](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1702)) and Abu I'sa classed it Hasan Sahih; in a long hadith narrated by At-Tirmidhi ([2325](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2325)), which Abu I'sa classed Hasan Sahih, about the parable of the world that are of four people; and in An-Nasa'i ([3178](https://sunnah.com/nasai:3178)), which was graded Sahih in Sahih al-Jam'i ([2388](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/408)), the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*Allah only helps this Ummah with its weak through their supplication, their prayers, and their sincerity.*" And to underline it once more: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*Whoever suffers from destitution (poverty) and he beseeches the people for it, his destitution shall not end. And whoever suffers from destitution and he beseeches Allah for it, Allah will send provisions to him, sooner or later.*" At-Tirmidhi ([2326](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2326)) and Abu I'sa classed it Hasan Sahih Gharib

> The Prophet (ﷺ) used to say: "*Allahumma inni a'udhu bika minal faqr, wal qil-lat, waz-zilat, wa a'udhu bika min an adh-lima au udh-lam*" (Ya Allah, I seek refuge in You from poverty, from lack (being in need) and humiliation, and I seek refuge in You from being wronged or wrong others) Abu Dawud ([1544](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1544)) which Shaykh Albani graded Sahih

> 'If you had a debt upon you similar to the mountain of Sir, Allah would fulfill it for you.' He (ﷺ) said: "*O Allah, suffice me with Your lawful against Your prohibited, and make me independent of all those besides You.* (Allahum-makfini bi-halalika a'n haramik(a), wa aghnini bi-fadlika a'm-man siwak)"
>
> <sup>Al-Mustadrak ([1/721](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/2014)), which Al-Hakim classed Sahih, and Ibn Hajar classed it Hasan in Nata'ij al-Afkar ([4/124](https://archive.org/details/WAQ101273/04_101276/page/n124/mode/2up))</sup>
>
> <sup>And, in Mujam as-Saghir ([558](https://shamela.ws/book/13068/661)), classed Hasan in Sahih at-Targhib ([1821](https://shamela.ws/book/171/989)), it is narrated:</sup>
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) told Mu'ath: "*Shall I not teach you a Du'a which, if you have debts as large as the mountain of Uhud, Allah will help you repay them? O Mu'ath, say: O Allah, Possessor of the kingdom, You give the kingdom to whom You will. In Your Hand is the good, and indeed You are able to do all things. You are the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful in this life and in the Hereafter. You give the kingdom to whom You will and You take it from whom You will, forgive me with Your Mercy which will render me not in need of the mercy of others*" (Allahumma Malikul Mulk, tu-til Mulk(a), man tasha-u wa tanzi'ul Mulk(a), mim-man tasha-u, wa tu'iz-zu man tasha-u, wa tudhilu man tasha-u bi-yadikal khayr, Innaka a'la kulli shay-in qadir - Rahmanud-dunya wal akhirah, t'u-tihuma man tasha-u wa tam-na'u minhuma man tasha-u, Ar-hamni Rahmatan tugh-nini biha a'n Rahmati man siwak)

And, we should never forget that this world is nothing compared to the Akhira:

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*If the world to Allah was equal to a mosquito's wing, then He would not allow the disbeliever to have a sip of water from it.*"
>
> <sup>At-Tirmidhi ([2320](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2320)) and Abu I'sa classed it Sahih Gharib; and in  ([2323](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2323)), classed Hasan Sahih, he (ﷺ) said:</sup>
>
> "*The Dunya compared to the Akhira is but like what one of you gets when placing his finger into the sea, so look at what you draw from it.*"
>
> ---
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*Nobody who dies and finds good from Allah* (in the Hereafter) *would wish to come back to this world even if he were given the whole world and whatever is in it, except the martyr who, on seeing the superiority of martyrdom, would like to come back to the world and get killed again* (in Allah's Cause)"
>
> <sup>Al-Bukhari ([2795](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2795))</sup>

<sup>Yahya ibn Mu'adh (ra), which was recorded in Hilyat al-Awliya ([10/57](https://shamela.ws/book/10495/15540)), said:</sup>

> 'The world has no value in the sight of its Rabb, yet it belongs to him. So, it is inappropriate that you value it while it is not yours.'

---

- **Here are some Verses of the Qur'an** (related to this topic):

"***And know that your possessions and your children are but a trial and that surely, with Allah is a mighty reward***" [Al-Anfal 8:28]

"***And certainly, We shall test you with something of fear, hunger, loss of wealth, lives and fruits, but give glad tidings to As-Sabirun (the patient). Who, when afflicted with calamity, say: ‘Truly, to Allah we belong and truly, to Him we shall return.’ They are those on whom are the Salawat (i.e. who are blessed and will be forgiven) from their Lord, and (they are those who) receive His Mercy, and it is they who are the guided ones***" [Al-Baqarah 2:155-157]

"***March forth, whether you are light (being healthy, young and wealthy) or heavy (being ill, old and poor), and strive hard with your wealth and your lives in the Cause of Allah. This is better for you, if you but knew***" [At-Tawbah 9:41]

"***Not equal are those of the believers who sit (at home), except those who are disabled (by injury or are blind or lame), and those who strive hard and fight in the Cause of Allah with their wealth and their lives. Allah has preferred in grades those who strive hard and fight with their wealth and their lives above those who sit (at home). Unto each, Allah has promised good (Paradise), but Allah has preferred those who strive hard and fight, above those who sit (at home) by a huge reward***" [An-Nis'a 4:95]

"***If you are grateful, I will surely increase you [in favor]; but if you deny, indeed, My punishment is severe***" [Ibrahim 14:7]

"***And whoever fears Allah, He will make for him a way out - And will provide for him from where he does not expect. And whoever relies upon Allah - then He is sufficient for him. Indeed, Allah will accomplish His purpose. Allah has already set for everything a [decreed] extent.***" [At-Talaq 65:2-3]

"... ***but indeed, the best provision is fear of Allah. And fear Me, O you of understanding.***" [Al-Baqarah 2:197]

---

Answer (score 2):

Here is verse from The Quran

***Know that this worldly life is no more than play, amusement, luxury, mutual boasting, and competition in wealth and children. This is like rain that causes plants to grow, to the delight of the planters. But later the plants dry up and you see them wither, then they are reduced to chaff. And in the Hereafter there will be either severe punishment or forgiveness and pleasure of Allah, whereas the life of this world is no more than the delusion of enjoyment.*** Al-Hadid 20

This Verse from The Quran will answer your question

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. I would first like to say I believe what you are asking is that if one believes in ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) and follow His (Glory Be To Him) commands and you want to do some certain dhikr, salawat, etc. to increase your wealth , etc. then that is fine. However, your belief should not be in Him (Glory Be To Him) due to making money and gaining status in this world.

> The Messenger of ALLAH (ﷺ) said, "The deeds are considered by the intentions, and a person will get the reward according to his intention. So whoever emigrated for ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) and His Messenger (peace be upon him), his emigration will be for ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) and His Messenger (peace be upon him); and whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration would be for what he emigrated for". [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

I will be discussing two parts regarding wealth.

1. Value of wealth
2. Ways to increase status / wealth / having ones needs taken care of in Islam

**Value of Wealth (Good and Bad)**

When it comes to wealth in it of self it is not a good or bad thing. It all depends on how it is being used. If are grateful and not haughty/prideful and use it for good then its good. If the wealth diverts you or helps you in your faith or you use it for bad then its not good.

**Wealth for Good Causes**

Quran

> And Solomon inherited David. He said, "O people, we have been taught the language of birds, **and we have been given from all things**. Indeed, this is evident bounty."

> And gathered for Solomon were his **soldiers of the jinn and men and birds**, and they were [marching] in rows

> So [Solomon] smiled, amused at her speech, and said, "My Lord, enable me1 to be grateful for Your favor which You have bestowed upon me and upon my parents and to do righteousness of which You approve. And admit me by Your mercy into [the ranks of] Your righteous servants."

(Chapter 27 verses 16,17,19)

Hadith

The following hadith is in regards to 'Abd ar-Rahmaan ibn 'Awf who was a wealthy sahabah and still received glad tidings of Jannah.

> “Abu Bakr will be in Paradise, ‘Umar will be in Paradise, ‘Usmaan will be in Paradise, ‘Ali will be in Paradise, Talhah will be in Paradise, al-Zubayr will be in Paradise, ‘Abd al-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf will be in Paradise, Sa’d will be in Paradise, Sa’eed will be in Paradise, and Abu ‘Ubaydah ibn al-Jarraah will be in Paradise.” (Narrated by al-Tirmidhi: 3680)

> Narrated Abu Salamah: that 'Abdur-Rahman bin 'Awf left a garden for the Mothers of the Believers that was sold for **four-hundred thousand.** (Tirmidhi in the chapter of virtues)

Sahabah Life

> Ahmad narrated in az-Zuhd (p. 36) that Sa‘eed ibn Jubayr said: ‘Abd ar-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf (may Allah be pleased with him) – who was one of the **wealthy Sahaabah** – could not be recognised from among his slaves.

**Wealth for Bad Causes (using it for bad or having greed/love for it)**

Quraan

> Competition in [worldly] increase diverts you (Chapter 102 verse 1)

Ahadith

> The Messenger of ALLAAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Two ravenous, hungry wolves spending the night in a pen of sheep while its owners are negligent, bloodthirsty and eating, are not quicker to wreak havoc than the **love of wealth and high status are to the religion of a Muslim.**” (Source: al-Mu’jam al-Awsaṭ 772)

> The Messenger of ALLAAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “The son of Adam grows old but remains young in two matters: **greed for wealth** and greed for long life.” (Sahih Muslim)

**Ways to increase status / wealth / having ones needs taken care of in Islam**

Here are a few Prophetic narrations that talk about increasing status and wealth. We do have to remember wealth in it of self is not a bad/evil thing. Same thing with any possession we have. It all depends on how we use it. Use for good you will receive rewards and use it for evil/bad then you will receive sin.

> A man came to the Prophet and said, “O Messenger of ALLAH, tell me about a deed which will make ALLAH and people love me.” The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Renounce the worldly life and ALLAH will love you. **Renounce what people possess and people will love you.**” (Ibn Majah)

> The Messenger of ALLAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “**Charity does not decrease wealth,** no one forgives another but that ALLAH increases his honor, and no one humbles himself for the sake of ALLAH but that ALLAH raises his status.” (Sahih Muslim)

**Hadith Note on Ways to Give Charity**: "Your smiling in the face of your brother is charity, commanding good and forbidding evil is charity, your giving directions to a man lost in the land is charity for you. Your seeing for a man with bad sight is a charity for you, your removal of a rock, a thorn or a bone from the road is charity for you. Your pouring what remains from your bucket into the bucket of your brother is charity for you." (Tirmidhi)

> Sayyiduna Ubayy ibn Ka’b (radiyallahu ‘anhu) said, “A man once came to Rasulullah (sallallahu ‘alayhi wa sallam) and said, ‘O Messenger of ALLAH! What do you think if I make my entire du’a only salutations upon you’? Nabi (sallallahu ‘alayhi wa sallam) said, **‘In that case, ALLAH Ta’ala will take care of whatever concerns you with regard to this world or the Hereafter.'**” [i.e. ALLAH Ta’ala will take care of all of your needs](Musnad Ahmad, vol. 5 pg. 136)

> The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, Allah Almighty says: O son of Adam, suffice Me with four cycles of prayer at the beginning of the morning and by them I will suffice you for the rest of your day.” (Musnad Ahmad)

**Have a nice day!**

Comment: it would have been better if you have discussed or rather elaborated/clarified in your own words.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem, As Salaamu 3laykum, I hope you are doing well. I thought it was not necessary because the ahadith are self explanatory. JazakaALLAH Khairan for your opinion.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem As Salaamu 3laykum, answer has been revised.